# From relative convexity to modulus of continuity estimates for the dual gradient mapping

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-analysis, duality, continuity, smoothness

Let $F: \mathbf{R}^d \to \mathbf{R}$ be a convex function, let $m > 0$, and define $Q_m: \mathbf{R}^d \to \mathbf{R}$ to be the mapping $x \mapsto \frac{m}{2} \| x \|_2^2$. One says that $F$ is $m$-strongly convex if $F - Q_m$ is convex. A (somewhat indirect) consequence of this is that if one defines for $y \in \mathbf{R}^d$

\begin{align}
\mathsf{dual\_grad}_F: y \mapsto \arg\max \left\{ \langle x, y \rangle - F (x) : x \in \mathbf{R}^d \right\},
\end{align}

(named as such due to the fact that $\mathsf{dual\_grad}_F = \nabla F^*$, where $F^*$ is the convex dual of $F$)

then it follows that $\mathsf{dual\_grad}$ is Lipschitz, with constant at most $m^{-1}$. Note that $\mathsf{dual\_grad}_{Q_m}$ is Lipschitz with constant *exactly* $m^{-1}$.

One can thus interpret this result as saying for a specific convex $G$ that

> if $F$ is at least as convex as $G$,
>
> > then $\mathsf{dual\_grad}_F$ has
> > a modulus of continuity which is at least as smooth as that of
> > $\mathsf{dual\_grad}_G$.

**My question** is whether a result of this form is known to hold for more general convex $G$ than quadratic.

Some context / caveats:

- I am aware that convex duality allows for one to transfer primal convexity into dual smoothness in various forms, e.g. bounding the Hessian from either side. I emphasise that I am specifically interested in results which directly bound the modulus of continuity of $\mathsf{dual\_grad}_F$, as this is the relevant quantity for my application. If it turns out that this is readily deduced from the Hessian bounds, then I would like to see how the deduction takes place.
- I am aware of work in recent years in the optimisation community involving assumptions of "relative smoothness", "relative strong convexity", and similar; I have not been able to find in that literature the results which I seek, though it is possible that they do exist there.
- I would like to accommodate fairly general choices of $G$, for whom the Hessian is allowed to potentially vanish or blow up in suitable limits.
- To the extent that there is a clear distinction in the context of this question, I ideally seek a result which is quantitative rather than qualitative, i.e. given a specific $F$ and $G$, I should in some sense be able to extract concrete bounds on the modulus of continuity of $\mathsf{dual\_grad}_F$ in terms of that of $\mathsf{dual\_grad}_G$.
- I am somewhat flexible on how "more convex than" is interpreted, though the additive form alluded to in the main question would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $F = G + H$, with $G$ and $H$ both convex. Suppose that $G$ satisfies the strong injectivity estimate

\begin{align}
\langle \nabla G(x) - \nabla G(y), x - y \rangle \geqslant \alpha_G ( \| x - y\| ) \cdot \| x - y \|
\end{align}

for some suitable positive, increasing $\alpha_G$. Applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, this entails that

\begin{align}
\langle \nabla G(x) - \nabla G(y), x - y \rangle \leqslant \| \nabla G(x) - \nabla G(y) \| \cdot \| x - y \|,
\end{align}

and so by rearranging,

\begin{align}
\| \nabla G(x) - \nabla G(y) \| \geqslant \alpha_G ( \| x - y\| ),
\end{align}

Moreover, taking $x = \nabla G^* (u)$, $y = \nabla G^* (v)$, this entails that

\begin{align}
\| \nabla G^* (u) - \nabla G^* (v) \| \leqslant \alpha_G^{-1} (\| u - v \|).
\end{align}

Returning to the original problem, one uses convexity of $H$ to argue that

\begin{align}
\langle \nabla F(x) - \nabla F(y), x - y \rangle \geqslant \langle \nabla G(x) - \nabla G(y), x - y \rangle \geqslant \alpha_G ( \| x - y\| ) \cdot \| x - y \|.
\end{align}

Again applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, one has that

\begin{align}
\langle \nabla F(x) - \nabla F(y), x - y \rangle \leqslant \| \nabla F(x) - \nabla F(y) \| \cdot \| x - y \|,
\end{align}

and so by rearranging, it follows that

\begin{align}
\| \nabla F(x) - \nabla F(y) \| \geqslant \alpha_G ( \| x - y\| ).
\end{align}

Setting $x = \nabla F^* (u)$, $y = \nabla F^* (v)$ and inverting $\alpha_G$, one obtains the estimate

\begin{align}
\| \nabla F^* (u) - \nabla F^* (v) \| \leqslant \alpha_G^{-1} (\| u - v \|),
\end{align}

i.e. $\nabla F^*$ admits a modulus of continuity estimate which matches that of $\nabla G^*$.